# -bash: a: command not found on Terminal startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, terminal

When starting Terminal on Mac OS 10.9.5, I get a message that says:

Last login: Sun Sep 28 08:16:35 on ttys000
-bash: a: command not found
iMac:~ jamesncampbell$

The second line is causing me worry, as I've never seen it before and it started happening after a failed installation of RoR. I've checked other threads but none of the solutions offered have worked for me. I'm a newb with Terminal commands so please take that into consideration when offering solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` is trying to call `a`, which is not a function or command. I would search those files for a solitary `a` somewhere and remove it.

Comment: @arco444 Thank you! There was a lone 'a' in my .bash_profile. Much appreciated